# Set-up GIT deployment on server running plesk

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, git, plesk

I have a lot of experience with Linux/Unix based systems.  I've been setting up many GIT deployments, from my own administered dedicated stacks, shared hosts, Debian, CentOS, RHEL, OpenBSD.  Yet one server with Plesk and all hell breaks lose.

My problem is with permissions.  Plesk stupidly sets up a group called `psaserv` and `psacln`. These groups indirectly cause me enormous grief and pain when trying to do anything across the system (for the record Plesk simply allows full ROOT password login via ssh, and destroys simple SSH key auth because of the above damn groups).

- I have installed GIT
- I created a new user `mygit` (which has a bare repository: `/home/mygit/somesite.com`)
- I create a bare repository at `/var/www/vhosts/somesite.com/repo.git`
- I set a remote: `git remote add origin /home/mygit/somesite.com`

So far, so good.  But when i check the readability:

```
[[ -r "/home/mygit/somesite.com" ]] && echo "Y";
```

Nothing!  Clearly no read permissions?

I can't simply push to `/var/www/vhosts/somesite.com/repo.git` because SSH keys wont work, because the whole `psaserv`/`psacln` groups and SSH permissions around multi-group thing.

Surely, i'm not the first person to be setting up a GIT deployment to a server where plesk is present?

Answer (score 0):

The Plesk team released an extension to help with just that a month after your question. Check out [Gitman](https://devblog.plesk.com/2015/12/gitman/)